# How to apply ItemAdd event to custom folder? Outlook 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to use ItemAdd event method to monitor when new items were added to my subfolder under Inbox.

My dir structure is like this:

```
- Inbox 
- - subfolder
```

I want to run the code when new email is added to a subfolder (the reason is I am using a rule that redirects certain emails to this subfolder).

Currently I am monitoring my Inbox using this:

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
   Set olInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).items
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
/* Code here */ 
End Sub
```

but when I try to do it for a subfolder

```
Set subfolderItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("subfolder").items 
Private Sub subfolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
```

it doesn't work. Why? How can I capture when new email is added?

Comment: ...Perfect question which is completely not a duplicate of the marked duplicate. Triggering events on subfolders is a sub question of the duplicate marked, not a duplicate. It is more precise. I wish the community would be more forgiving in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not mention

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items
```

You probably forgot

```
Private WithEvents subfolderItems As Items
```

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare subfolderItems variable on the global level to make sure it stays alive.